# Touch bar behaves differently after upgrading to Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, touch-bar

It used to be that my volume controls etc. showed up as well as the lock screen when I tapped the touch bar under Sierra. Now the only items that appear on the touch bar are related to the currently active application. Eg, right now I just see some typing assistance and esc key or Chrome specific items. Before I could just tap it and I'd see volume and lock screen.

I've configured the touch bar in system preferences and these items are in my bar there. How do I get non-application specific items to appear?